# How to make sure only one request send out at same time in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, service, singleton

All:

**I am wondering if someone can show me some best practices to design a service to do http request which can only allow request sent out until all requests finished(kinda like how to implement singleton work mode)**

Right now, what I think out is design a service which has a indicator variable to show current status of this service's working but I guess this is very bad:

```
var app = angular.module("testsingletask", []);

app.directive("datafetcher", function($http){

    this.idle = true;
    this.getdata = function(dataurl){

        var self = this;
        var datapromise = null;
        if(self.idle){
            datapromise = $http.get(dataurl)
                 .then(function(data){
                     self.idle = true;
                     return data;
                 }, function(error){
                     self.idle = true;
                     return error;
                 });
        } // end of if block
        return datapromise;

    } // end of this.getdata

});
```

And the way we use it is like:

```
var data = datafetcher.getdata("dataurl");
if(data){
    data.then(function(return_data){}, function(return_err){});
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want a service that makes a limited amount of requests? I think it would be best to call the service when the page loads, set a property in a service equal to the return data (services persist throughout views/controllers rendering because it is a singleton), and then whenever a conroller/factory/service needs that data, it can just get the data from the service property instead of calling the get method.

Edit: If you want to do something like "I want a service that can only be called 5 times" then just create a property in your service that counts the number of times the get method has been called, increment it on each call, and in the get method check that the services increment property is < 5.

Comment: Thanks, actually what I want is very simple, the situation is sometimes, I set ng-click to init a http request to get data, but if the user click a lot of times in a short time(intentional or not), it will init tons of requests which to get same data. I want to limit this by only allowing sending request when there is no request running

Comment: There's a simple fix to that. Set a boolean property (lets call it "calling") on your $scope. Set it to false in the get call. Set it to true when the data returns in your .then call. Then on the view, on the button that the user presses to make the get call, set an ng-disabled="!calling" on the button element. That way the button cannot be clicked when data is being retrieved. This is a common approach used when implementing a "loading" screen and will work for your case as well.